# Faster Python MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, performance

I use mysql.connector (MySQLdb Python implementation?) to access MySQL. The transfer from a select statement from a cursor isn't that fast.

Is there a way to speed up the code?

Maybe another library? Which? (I have Windows and Python 3.1)
Maybe a row retrieval different from iterating over the cursor?

Comment: Why do you believe it's the client library and not your query that makes things slow? Besides that, show some code.

Comment: Launching the same query in an SQL Browser is much faster. The code is spread but shouldn't take long. If it cannot be the SQL access but is in the Python code, then I'll work it out myself. That's not the question here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default `MySQLdb` cursor fetches the entire query result at once from the server. Conversion of this data to a Python list of tuples can consume a lot of memory and time.

Use [MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) when you want to make a huge query and
pull results from the server one at a time. Note, however, that when using SSCursor, [no other query can be made](http://mysql-python.blogspot.com/2010/02/asynchronous-programming-and-mysqldb.html) on the `connection` until the entire result set has been fetched.

```
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors as cursors
connection = MySQLdb.connect(
    ...
    cursorclass = cursors.SSCursor)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
for row in cursor:
    ...
```

Or, use [oursql](http://packages.python.org/oursql/), an alternative Python driver for MySQL. One of the features of oursql is that it [fetchs rows lazily](http://packages.python.org/oursql/tutorial.html#row-streaming-out).

Comment: Thanks! Interesting tips :) I'll try to examine these possibilities.

Comment: The executemany tip was very helpful. Moreover I noticed that fetchall is considerably faster than cursor access! The SSCursor thing I haven't understood yet, but I'll keep that in mind :)

Comment: @unutbu Does mysql support server side query? I think mysql will send record one by one once it retrieves the record immediately send out. It won't cache the data. Otherwise, if someone wants to kill mysql server just send couple big tables SSCursor, then mysql server memory will ran out.

Comment: @FengWang: Can you elaborate? I don't think I understand your question.