# Optimizing Python MySQL/Connector Speed

Tags: python, mysql, csv, pandas

I have a table in MySQL that contains the following columns:

```
id int(11)
contract_id int(11)
datetime datetime
open decimal(18, 10)
high decimal(18, 10)
low decimal(18, 10)
close decimal(18, 10)
```

The table is fairly large (> 300 millions rows), but queries made within the database are executed within half a second even when they return 300,000 rows. However, when I retrieve data from Python it is very slow (same request goes from 0.5s in MySQL Workbench to 34s in Python):

```
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector 

con = mysql.connector.connect(**CONFIG) 
cur = con.cursor()

def get_data1():
    df = pd.read_sql(
        """
        SELECT datetime, open, high, low, close 
        FROM prices
        WHERE contract_id = 1 
            AND datetime >= '2015-01-01 09:00:00' 
            AND datetime <= '2015-10-15 16:00:00'; 
        """, con)
    return df
```

I found that exporting data from MySQL to a flat file and then reading it in Python was 23x faster than a direct query on the database:

```
def get_data2():
    cur.execute(
        """
        SELECT datetime, open, high, low, close 
        FROM prices
        WHERE contract_id = 1 
            AND datetime >= '2015-01-01 09:00:00' 
            AND datetime <= '2015-10-15 16:00:00'
        INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Data/Temp.csv'
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        ENCLOSED BY '"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY "\n";
        """)
    return pd.read_csv('C:/Data/Temp.csv')
```

How can it be? I suspect that this is related to the data type conversion. Any idea how to make the function `get_data1` faster without having to first export to CSV? Thank you.

Comment: just saw this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895837/faster-python-mysql and was wondering if it helps?
also, i see that you're using mysql connector and calling `pd.read_sql`... have you tried using sqlalchemy with the newer function http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html

Comment: also, i've had to try alternatives to sqlalchemy and here is an example of what i used with mysql connector: https://gist.github.com/msure/24ce45067d598fa7a5b6

Comment: Thanks, I will try that though I don't expect it to significantly increase performance - I believe the issue is in the data type conversion.

Answer (score 3):

The following solution is 3x faster than the initial one (12s vs. 34s):

```
import mysql.connector
con = mysql.connector.connect(**CONFIG)
cur = con.cursor()
class MySQLConverter(mysql.connector.conversion.MySQLConverter):
    def _DECIMAL_to_python(self, value, desc=None):
        return float(value)
    _NEWDECIMAL_to_python = _DECIMAL_to_python

con.set_converter_class(MySQLConverter)
```

It converts MySQL decimal type into Python float instead of decimal.Decimal, which is faster. It is still much slower than the "CSV solution" that takes 1.57s to complete. Still digging...